# Does reference counting as a garbage collection method cause memory leaks in Python?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, circular-reference, reference-counting

From [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/web2py/dmN54cpMuXo/lufvxmaQMLUJ) discussion:

> For example the following code
>
> ```
>  class A: pass 
>  a=A() 
>  a.b=a
> ```
>
> causes a memory leak in ANY python program.

Could you please exactly explain what is the problem behind the scenes and how to prevent it?

Comment: "For example the following code ... causes a memory leak in ANY python program" - no it doesn't.

Comment: That hasn't been the case since Python2.0 (15 years ago!)

Comment: well, I quoted massimo depedro, (a computer scientist) who has developed Web2Py framework. @massimo

Answer (score 1):

Reference counting won't free that object because its reference count never goes to zero. What you have there is a case of cyclical references (where an object contains a reference to itself, or to another object that points back to it, etc.) and reference counting simply isn't the right solution to that problem.

(To really illustrate the problem you should probably include `del a` as the last line, but we'll let that slide...)

In any case, this is why Python has, in addition to reference counting, an actual garbage collector which finds and frees up memory that can not be reached. So even the object formerly known as `a` will eventually be collected, it just might not happen immediately.

Other Python implementations may use different memory management strategies. For example Jython and IronPython use the memory management of their underlying VMs, the Java virtual machine and the .Net CLR respectively.

Comment: Thank you,  But do you suggest using ``del`` every time we cyclical references?

Comment: No, it's just that until you do `del a` there is an obvious reference to the instance, and it is therefore clear why the reference counter didn't delete it.

Comment: So, can you explain examples of how a code might lead to memory leak (maybe by referencing to itself)?

Comment: You could call into a C library (or some other compiled language) that has a memory leak. You could run your Python code on a buggy or old interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

In Python1.x, the situation looked like this

```
class A: pass
```

1 reference to A

```
a=A()
```

2 references to A, 1 reference to an instance of A

```
a.b=a
```

2 references to A, 2 references to the same instance of A

```
del a
```

2 references to A, 1 (inaccessible) reference to our instance of A

This is what is meant by leaked memory

Python has had a cyclic garbage collector since 2000, so this will (usually) find the unreachable reference and release it.

Comment: Why you said ``usually``?  are there cases that gc can not find those?

Comment: Yes. For classes that define `__del__` methods. This is discussed later in the thread you linked to. Massimo was mistaken because attempting to add `__del__` methods to see when objects are gc'd prevents the cyclic collection from working on them.

Comment: [In 3.4 and later](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/), objects with `__del__` methods can participate in reference cycles without causing leaks, since they changed the finalization system. The price is that finalizers can see already-finalized objects in a reference cycle and have to deal with them correctly.